# Welding individual line segments into one LineString using Shapely

Tags: python, shapely

I'm using Shapely in python and I'm given a `MultiLineString` with a bunch of `Linestring` objects. I can guarantee that all the `LineString` objects are simple lines with only 2 vertices and that they are all part of one single line (no branches).

I want to "connect-the-dots" and create a single `LineString`.

Do I need to write a recursive welding method for this or is there a faster way?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use `shapely`'s [`ops.linemerge`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.ops.linemerge) to accomplish this:

```
from shapely import geometry, ops

# create three lines
line_a = geometry.LineString([[0,0], [1,1]])
line_b = geometry.LineString([[1,1], [1,0]])
line_c = geometry.LineString([[1,0], [2,0]])

# combine them into a multi-linestring
multi_line = geometry.MultiLineString([line_a, line_b, line_c])
print(multi_line)  # prints MULTILINESTRING ((0 0, 1 1), (1 1, 2 2), (2 2, 3 3))

# you can now merge the lines
merged_line = ops.linemerge(multi_line)
print(merged_line)  # prints LINESTRING (0 0, 1 1, 2 2, 3 3)

# if your lines aren't contiguous
line_a = geometry.LineString([[0,0], [1,1]])
line_b = geometry.LineString([[1,1], [1,0]])
line_c = geometry.LineString([[2,0], [3,0]])

# combine them into a multi-linestring
multi_line = geometry.MultiLineString([line_a, line_b, line_c])
print(multi_line)  # prints MULTILINESTRING ((0 0, 1 1), (1 1, 1 0), (2 0, 3 0))

# note that it will now merge only the contiguous portions into a component of a new multi-linestring
merged_line = ops.linemerge(multi_line)
print(merged_line)  # prints MULTILINESTRING ((0 0, 1 1, 1 0), (2 0, 3 0))
```

Comment: How can I know which linestring was merged ? I want to receive a list like: merged = [[line_a,line_b],[line_c]]

Comment: You could loop through a list of your individual lines and check whether the new merged line `contains()` the individual lines. Those not contained would not have been merged. e.g. `merged_line.contains(line_a)` which would return a boolean `True` or `False`

Comment: thanks a lot. How do you check if the line is contained in the merged_lines ?

Comment: Per the `merged_line.contains(line_a)` bit. Once you've created the merged line it will have access to the shapely method `contains` which then lets you check whether it contains other shapely geometry. In this case, a merged line will contain an individual line from which it was merged because they overlap exactly.

Comment: ah, I didn't understand that ".contains(line_a)" was a prewritten function. perfect. Thanks a lot !

Comment: sorry, to bother you again... but do you know who to merge lines which are "close" (within a certain maximum distance from each other) ? I am asking because I am seeing many lines which should be merged, but due to a small gab between them, they are not merged.

Comment: I can't remember if Shapely has a snap to grid method but you could try rounding all of your coordinates to an acceptable level of precision, e.g. the nearest centimeter or metre, which may resolve depending on your specific case. If you have access to PostGIS it is possible to snap coordinates to a grid, though this would get more involved.

Answer (score 5):

`shapely.ops.linemerge` works if the lines are contiguous ("tips" coincide with the "tails" of the constituent lines), but if they are non-contiguous (if there's a gap between the tips and tails) it returns another MultiLineString. If your constituent lines are well-ordered (with one line ending near the start of the next line) but have a tip-to-tail gap, you can extract the coordinates and use them make a new simple line. This approach also works for multi-lines made of more complex sublines (i.e. sublines with more than two points).

```
import shapely

# Make a MultiLineString to use for the example
inlines = shapely.geometry.MultiLineString(
    [shapely.geometry.LineString([(0,0),(0,0.9)]), 
     shapely.geometry.LineString([(0,1),(1,1)])]
)

# Put the sub-line coordinates into a list of sublists
outcoords = [list(i.coords) for i in inlines]

# Flatten the list of sublists and use it to make a new line
outline = shapely.geometry.LineString([i for sublist in outcoords for i in sublist])
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you could do it with Shapely using shapely.ops.linemerge() method.

It looks like it could take a list of lines as input and merge them. I used the 'polygonize' method before and it does take a list of lines.

Take a look at the doc here: http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#shapely.ops.linemerge

Comment: Do you know how to merge lines which are "close" (within a certain maximum distance from each other) ?

Comment: polygonize_full works somewhat better, but I got some strange datastructures as a result

Answer (score 2):

`shapely.ops.linemerge()` failed for some of my lines so I had to do it manually.
It seems to fail for the lines that "returned" to itself, i.e., going through the same point more than once. For my case, I know that the lines are in the correct order so it was easy to write a small function to merge them.

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString
from typing import List


def merge_lines(lines: List[LineString]) -> LineString:
    last = None
    points = []
    for line in lines:
        current = line.coords[0]

        if last is None:
            points.extend(line.coords)
        else:
            if last == current:
                points.extend(line.coords[1:])
            else:
                print('Skipping to merge {} {}'.format(last, current))
                return None
        last = line.coords[-1]
    return LineString(points)
```

Hope it helps someone